# Angularjs : print preview pop-up not working or opening in any browser using pdf-js Viewer

Tags: angularjs

[image]

[image]
I am using `pdf-js viewer` for pdf in angularjs but unable to open the print preview pop-up when clicking on print button.

HTML Code

```
<div>
   <pdfjs-viewer data="data">
   </pdfjs-viewer>
</div>
```

Js Code

```
otherreportService.viewTestReport($stateParams.ApptId,$stateParams.Doctid)
                .then(function (response) {
                            $scope.data = new Uint8Array(response);
                    },
                    function (err) {
                        return false;
                    });
```

Comment: Are you using pdf.js viewer directive? Please share your HTML code where you added the directive.

Comment: Yes.  I am using pdf.js Viewer Directive.                                                
HTML Code :- <pdfjs-viewer data="data"></pdfjs-viewer>

Comment: What is "data"? Have you passed it as Uint8Array?

Comment: Yes.Its Uint8Array

Comment: Please share the necessary code. Your problem statement is not enough to answer this.

Comment: Giving us more details what you have tried already will help you to get perfect answers !

Comment: I have updated my question with all the code